# Cannot get a command prompt after "start /system1/sol1"

Tags: ipmi

This is going to be difficult to explain so please bear with me.  I normally putty into IPMI like this:

```
-> start /system1/sol1
/system1/sol1
press <Enter>, <Esc>, and then <T> to terminate session
(press the keys in sequence, one after the other)
```

After that, I should get this prompt:  mdexhost console login:

But the warning and the prompt just scroll through no matter what keys I hit.  I can't get to the prompt and I can't stop the program.  Today, I tried ipmitool from a remote Linux box.  I first did a power cycle and then tried again and the result was the same (see below).

I've also tried to power down the box, disconnect the power cord and start it all up again.  I'm not sure how to recover from this.

Any help and it's beers on me.

```
[mcraig@Low-SDI ~]$ ipmitool -I lanplus -H 10.231.4.9 -U ADMIN chassis power cycle
Password:
Chassis Power Control: Cycle
[mcraig@Low-SDI ~]$ ipmitool -I lanplus -H 10.231.4.9 -U ADMIN -a sol activate
Password:
Error: Unable to establish IPMI v2 / RMCP+ session
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[mcraig@Low-SDI ~]$ ipmitool -I lanplus -H 10.231.4.9 -U ADMIN -a sol activate
Password:
[SOL Session operational.  Use ~? for help]
--|

mdexhost console login: ^C

|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| This system is for the use of authorized users only.            |
| Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in |
| excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their   |
| activities on this system monitored and recorded by system      |
| personnel.                                                      |
|                                                                 |
| In the course of monitoring individuals improperly using this   |
| system, or in the course of system maintenance, the activities  |
| of authorized users may also be monitored.                      |
|                                                                 |
| Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring  |
| and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible         |
| evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the |
| evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement officials.       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|

mdexhost console login: ^C

|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| This system is for the use of authorized users only.            |
| Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in |
| excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their   |
| activities on this system monitored and recorded by system      |
| personnel.                                                      |
|                                                                 |
| In the course of monitoring individuals improperly using this   |
| system, or in the course of system maintenance, the activities  |
| of authorized users may also be monitored.                      |
|                                                                 |
| Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring  |
| and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible         |
| evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the |
| evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement officials.       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|

mdexhost console login: ^C

|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| This system is for the use of authorized users only.            |
| Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in |
| excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their   |
| activities on this system monitored and record
```

Comment: Lol, by the way I am an "authorized user".  System worked properly until Thursday last week.  Don't know what changed, thus the mystery.

Comment: Was also having an issue and then found https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=17662